# WCF and Autofac w/Extensionless Services

Tags: wcf, autofac

I am having a heck of a time trying to get this to work.

I want Autofac to manage my WCF services and use extension less services.

Any ideas why this does not work?

```
namespace SAIF.Services.WCF.Host
{
    using System;
    using System.ServiceModel.Activation;
    using System.Web;
    using System.Web.Routing;
    using Autofac;
    using Autofac.Integration.Wcf;
    using SAIF.Core.Domain;
    using SAIF.Core.Domain.Model;
    using SAIF.Repositories;
    using SAIF.Services.WCF.Core;
    using SAIF.Services.WCF.Services;

    public class Global : HttpApplication
    {
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // Create Routes
            var factory = new AutofacServiceHostFactory();
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("FileService", factory, typeof(SAIF.Services.WCF.Core.IFileService)));
            RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("WebContext", factory, typeof(SAIF.Services.WCF.Core.IWebContextService)));

            // Autofac Config
            var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

            builder.Register(x => new EFUnitOfWork())
                .As<EFUnitOfWork>()
                .As<IUnitOfWork>();

            builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(Repository<>))
                .As(typeof(IRepository<>));

            builder.Register(x => new FileService())
                .As<IFileService>();

            builder.Register(x => new WebContextService(x.Resolve<IRepository<WebContextItem>>(), x.Resolve<IUnitOfWork>()))
                .As<IWebContextService>();

            AutofacHostFactory.Container = builder.Build();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to step through? any errors? what's in the container at the end?

Comment: Everything looks good when stepping through it. COntainer builds, registrations are there, just the code does not work!

Answer (score 1):

<del>I'm not sure if the Application_Start method of the Global.asax gets called by WAS in IIS.</del>

[This SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2453353/what-is-the-global-asax-application-start-equivalent-when-using-was-in-iis7) seems to be similar to what you are looking for and links to [this blog post](http://consultingblogs.emc.com/matthall/archive/2009/08/18/castle-windsor-and-non-http-protocol-wcf-services.aspx)

Implement an AppInitialize method and put it in the [App_Code](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t990ks23(VS.80).aspx) folder.

```
public class InitialiseService
{
   /// <summary>
   /// AppInitialize method to register the IOC container.
   /// </summary>
   public static void AppInitialize()
   {
       // Create Routes
       var factory = new AutofacServiceHostFactory();
       RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("FileService", factory, typeof(SAIF.Services.WCF.Core.IFileService)));
       RouteTable.Routes.Add(new ServiceRoute("WebContext", factory, typeof(SAIF.Services.WCF.Core.IWebContextService)));

       // Autofac Config
       var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

       //...the rest of your code...
   }
}
```

[Another SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921802/serviceroute-webservicehostfactory-kills-wsdl-generation-how-to-create-extens) talks about using **ServiceHostFactory** rather than **WebServiceHostFactory**.

Can you try using that instead of the AutofacServiceHostFactory?

***Update***

This is an old question/answer but I have since tried following the instructions on Autofac documentation

see https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration#WAS_Hosting_Extensionless_Services

A key part to *extensionless* routing in is adding the UrlRoutingModule

Comment: Application_Start does get fired... Still stumped.

Comment: true, but can you try initializing stuff here?

Comment: Autofac has it's own implementations of Service Factories `AutofacServiceHostFactory`

Comment: Any improvement on that ? I got a similar problem. See my detailed steps at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21093942)