# Use Autofac with a WCF service using WAS

Tags: c#, wcf, autofac, was

I like the WCF 4.0 capabality to host a service without an .svc file by setting a serviceActivations in the config file. It work great using the default service factory but now I'm trying to do the same using the AutofaServiceHostFactory so my dependencies will be properly injected. In all scenarios I tried, I still got this error when I try to access to service : **The service 'WCFAutofacWiring.MyService' configured for WCF is not registered with the Autofac container**. I host my service in an empty asp.net web site. Here's what I did :

Web.config :

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment>
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory"
     relativeAddress="~/WASCurrentTime.svc"
     service="WCFAutofacWiring.MyService" />
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

Then, I put a file in the app_code folder to register my dependency as stated in the Autofac documentation ([Autofac WcfIntegration](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/WcfIntegration)) and I confirmed with the debugger that the code is called at service start :

```
public static class AppStart
{
    public static void AppInitialize()
    {
        AutofacHostFactory.Container = new AutofacBootstrapper().Configure();
    } 
}
```

Finally, here's my registrations :

```
public class AutofacBootstrapper
{
    public IContainer Configure()
    {
        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        // register types 
        builder.Register<ILanguageProvider>(x => new MyLanguageProvider("en-US"));
        builder.RegisterType<MyService>();

        return builder.Build();
    }
}
```

My service works perfectly if a use an .svc file instead of serviceActivation but I find it wasteful to create an .svc file if the only reason is to setup a factory that I can specify in my web.config.

Any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried using the fully-qualified name for the service? I.e. `service="WCFAutofacWiring.MyService, MyAssembly"`.

Comment: Yes, doesn't work. For what I can see, the problem doesn't come from the fact the type cannot be resolved (the error message contains the assembly name so I'm pretty sure it has been found) but that the registrations aren't used (or aren't correct). Another possibility is that AutofacHostFactory.Container doesn't work the same in a WAS context.

Comment: That's not the assembly name in the error message, it's what you specified in the config. It could be anything :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [Autofac source](https://code.google.com/p/autofac/source/browse/Core/Source/Autofac.Integration.Wcf/DefaultServiceImplementationDataProvider.cs#66), the exception is thrown if either a keyed resolution with the given string (from config) or a typed resolution using [`Type.GetType`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3f99sx1.aspx) for the given string fails.

In your case the `Type.GetType` method probably returns `null` because you haven't specified a   [`Type.AssemblyQualifiedName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.assemblyqualifiedname.aspx) in the config.

Try getting `typeof(MyService).AssemblyQualifiedName` and insert that into the config.

Comment: Hi. You didn't gave me the exact answer BUT you give me the hint I needed to fix the problem. The problem was in both web.config, (the missing assembly) and in the registration. I tried both fixes individually before but putting it together fixed the problem. Thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity (and to potentially help others later), what was wrong with the registration?

Comment: The qualified name was the problem indeed. What fixed my problems: 1. in web.config: qualified name for service name and endpoint contract; 2. qualified name in .svc Service

Comment: That AssemblyQualifiedName really helps. need to get that and put it to "serviceHostingEnvironment" tab (I am using svc-less config) to work. like this: <serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add factory="Autofac.Integration.Wcf.AutofacServiceHostFactory"
         relativeAddress="~/IService.svc"
         service="Put that AssemblyQualifiedName here"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>